# Are there way to prevent HDD flooding from users?

Tags: configuration, linux, traffic

We have several users on linux computing pool, are there way to "shape" the IO per user(like  a net shaping analogue..)?
Is it possible?
Can we restrict the number of IO threads per user?

Thanks.
Arman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [cgroups](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/cgroups.txt) feature to set up a "fair share" hierarchy for disk bandwidth.

Comment: WOW This is a nice future! I will test it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of at an OS level, but VMware allows I/O limits per virtual machine, if that is of any use.

Comment: thanks good to know. Is VMWare uses OS functions? or it has a own policy?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [quotas](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialQuotas.html) to set a limit on space, but that doesn't limit IO.

Comment: We disabled our quotas, the server has practically infinite data space and users are able to read and write Tb data..The trouble is IO:(